# cygwin 64 library: undefined reference, relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol

Tags: c, cygwin

Netbeans + Cygwin 64, windows 7

Trying to build project originally composed on visual C.

Basically I searched and understood that it's some cygwin problem and I'm missing some library that visual C has. However I don't understand how to fix it...

below is the hefty message:

```
Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows
gcc -o dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/timerdac build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/EOGTesteingOut.o -lgdi32
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/EOGTesteingOut.o: In function `main':
/cygdrive/D/timerDACcode/EOGTester/EOGTesteingOut.c:39: multiple definition of `main'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:/cygdrive/D/timerDACcode/EOGTester/DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:40: first defined here
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/EOGTesteingOut.o: In function `ClearScreen':
/cygdrive/D/timerDACcode/EOGTester/EOGTesteingOut.c:267: multiple definition of `ClearScreen'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:/cygdrive/D/timerDACcode/EOGTester/DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:930: first defined here
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/EOGTesteingOut.o: In function `MoveCursor':
/cygdrive/D/timerDACcode/EOGTester/EOGTesteingOut.c:293: multiple definition of `MoveCursor'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:/cygdrive/D/timerDACcode/EOGTester/DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:956: first defined here
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/EOGTesteingOut.o: In function `GetTextCursor':
/cygdrive/D/timerDACcode/EOGTester/EOGTesteingOut.c:320: multiple definition of `GetTextCursor'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:/cygdrive/D/timerDACcode/EOGTester/DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:983: first defined here
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x1b6): undefined reference to `__imp_waveOutOpen'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x1b6): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__imp_waveOutOpen'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x1dc): undefined reference to `cbDeclareRevision'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x1dc): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `cbDeclareRevision'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x1f1): undefined reference to `cbErrHandling'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x1f1): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `cbErrHandling'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x21b): undefined reference to `cbGetConfig'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x21b): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `cbGetConfig'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x246): undefined reference to `cbWinBufAlloc32'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x246): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `cbWinBufAlloc32'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x26c): undefined reference to `cbWinBufAlloc'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x26c): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `cbWinBufAlloc'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x3bd): undefined reference to `cbAInScan'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x3bd): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `cbAInScan'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x3f8): undefined reference to `fftw_malloc'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x3f8): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `fftw_malloc'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x409): undefined reference to `fftw_malloc'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x409): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `fftw_malloc'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x43c): undefined reference to `fftw_plan_dft_1d'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x43c): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `fftw_plan_dft_1d'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x46f): undefined reference to `fftw_plan_dft_1d'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x46f): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x5b9): undefined reference to `fftw_execute'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x6b5): undefined reference to `cbGetStatus'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x732): undefined reference to `__imp_waveOutUnprepareHeader'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x77b): undefined reference to `__imp_waveOutPrepareHeader'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x7be): undefined reference to `__imp_waveOutWrite'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x14f3): undefined reference to `fftw_execute'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x1744): undefined reference to `fftw_execute'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x1ac0): undefined reference to `kbhit'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x1b1b): undefined reference to `cbStopBackground'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x1b3a): undefined reference to `fftw_destroy_plan'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x1b49): undefined reference to `fftw_destroy_plan'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x1b58): undefined reference to `fftw_free'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x1b67): undefined reference to `fftw_free'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x1b78): undefined reference to `__imp_waveOutClose'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/DaqInTesteingNewOut.o:DaqInTesteingNewOut.c:(.text+0x1bc4): undefined reference to `cbWinBufFree'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/EOGTesteingOut.o:EOGTesteingOut.c:(.text+0xcf): undefined reference to `cbDeclareRevision'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/EOGTesteingOut.o:EOGTesteingOut.c:(.text+0xe4): undefined reference to `cbErrHandling'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/EOGTesteingOut.o:EOGTesteingOut.c:(.text+0x10e): undefined reference to `cbGetConfig'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/EOGTesteingOut.o:EOGTesteingOut.c:(.text+0x139): undefined reference to `cbWinBufAlloc32'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/EOGTesteingOut.o:EOGTesteingOut.c:(.text+0x15f): undefined reference to `cbWinBufAlloc'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/EOGTesteingOut.o:EOGTesteingOut.c:(.text+0x2a4): undefined reference to `cbAInScan'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/EOGTesteingOut.o:EOGTesteingOut.c:(.text+0x2df): undefined reference to `cbGetStatus'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/EOGTesteingOut.o:EOGTesteingOut.c:(.text+0x497): undefined reference to `kbhit'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/EOGTesteingOut.o:EOGTesteingOut.c:(.text+0x502): undefined reference to `cbStopBackground'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/450961492/EOGTesteingOut.o:EOGTesteingOut.c:(.text+0x545): undefined reference to `cbWinBufFree'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:63: recipe for target 'dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/timerdac.exe' failed
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/timerdac.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/sam/Documents/NetBeansProjects/timerDAC'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:60: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/sam/Documents/NetBeansProjects/timerDAC'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 9s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the development libraries for fftw.  Install the `libfftw3-devel` package using the cygwin setup.exe installer.  Then try again.  You may need other libraries as well...